# Lagging local image loading in UItableview

Tags: ios, uiimageview, lazy-loading, grand-central-dispatch

I made an app which load images from photo library or image taken from camera into a table view , but UI freezes every time i scroll up/down or new image added. Here is how i am making the cell for table view .

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
     *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

    if (cell == nil) 
    { 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

        cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 70); 
    }

    NSError *attributesError = nil; NSString *workSpacePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 

    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]attributesOfItemAtPath:workSpacePath error:&attributesError]; 

    NSNumber * fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize]; 

    long long int fileKBSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue]/1024; 

if (fileKBSize > 1024) 
{ 
     cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"File name #%i (%lli MB)",indexPath.row + 1,fileKBSize / 1024]; 
}
else 
{ 
     cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"File name #%i (%lli KB)",indexPath.row + 1,fileKBSize]; 

}
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; NSString *descriptionString = [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

NSLog(@"descriptionString :%@",descriptionString); 

if ([[despDectionary objectForKey:descriptionString] length] > 0) 
{ 

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[despDectionary objectForKey:descriptionString]]; 

}
else
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"File Description"; 
}

dispatch_queue_t bg = dispatch_queue_create("Back Ground", NULL); 

dispatch_async(bg,^(void) 

{ 
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:workSpacePath]]; 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 

   //cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 70); cell.imageView.image = image; 

}); 

});

cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; 

UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 

button.frame = CGRectMake(250, 0, 49,56); 

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deletButotn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.tag = indexPath.row; 

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

[cell.contentView addSubview:button]; 

return cell; 

}
```

---

Can somebody please suggest me any solution?

Comment: Please format your code/question

Comment: Where does it freeze in code?  Try not to create a new dispatch queue for every image but use one of the system default low priority one.

Comment: It freezes while scrolling